# How to install plugins in TinyMCE correctly?

Tags: bootstrap-4, tinymce

I'm trying to install TinyMCE on my website

The table, link, and media plugins don't work. that is, a popup opens, but you can't enter a value in the fields - just select it from the list. There is only one error in the console - Please use the List plugin together with the Advanced List plugin.

Bootstrap and Tiny may conflict. But how to fix it?

code

```
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
   selector: 'textarea#default',
   language: 'ru',
   menubar: 'edit insert',
   toolbar: 'advlist image code link imagetools advcode media powerpaste codesample',
   plugins: 'advlist image code link imagetools advcode media powerpaste codesample',
   default_link_target: '_blank',
   image_list: [
    {title: 'My image 1', value: 'https://www.example.com/my1.gif'},
    {title: 'My image 2', value: 'http://www.moxiecode.com/my2.gif'}
  ]
});
  </script>

...

<textarea id='default'> </textarea>
```

[website](https://tipoblog.tw1.ru/public/scient.php) - (the last option at  will open tiny)

Comment: FYI When visiting your link, I am met with a privacy warning: `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This server could not prove that it is tipoblog.tw1.ru; its security certificate is from *.timeweb.ru. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.`

Comment: Yeah, when i install ssl all be alright. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different issues you seem to be experiencing:

## TinyMCE and Bootstrap:

The behavior you are describing is a common issue when using TinyMCE in Bootstrap, particularly in a dialog/modal. It is likely that you will need to override the built-in block on `focusin` in the Bootstrap dialog with this code:

```
// Prevent Bootstrap dialog from blocking focusin
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".tox-tinymce, .tox-tinymce-aux, .moxman-window, .tam-assetmanager-root").length) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

Here is a working Tiny Fiddle demonstration:
http://fiddle.tiny.cloud/gRgaab

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/bootstrap/#usingtinymceinabootstrapdialog

## Plugins vs Toolbar:

You also have the same items listed for your `plugins` and `toolbar` configurations:

```
 toolbar: 'advlist image code link imagetools advcode media powerpaste codesample',
 plugins: 'advlist image code link imagetools advcode media powerpaste codesample',
```

Plugins are not toolbar items. Plugins are bits of additional, optional functionality that can be added to the editor. Toolbar buttons are clickable UI elements that execute specific commands. These commands may be for plugin functionality, or for core-editor functionality.

A list of available toolbar buttons can be found here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/available-toolbar-buttons/

## Lists and Advanced Lists:

The console error:

```
Please use the List plugin together with the Advanced List plugin.
```

...is pretty thorough. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/advlist/):

> The Lists (`lists`) plugin must be activated for the `advlist` plugin to work.

This can be fixed by adding `lists` to your `plugin` configuration:

```
 plugins: 'lists advlist image code link imagetools advcode media powerpaste codesample',
```